# Undefined method only when not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I'm building a blog that includes tiered admin permissions. When I'm signed in using our seeded admin account I can see the index just fine. When I go to the page not signed in, something that should be filtered by the `before_action` I get an error saying undefined method `admin=' for nil:NilClass in my index view.

When I'm not signed in, current_user should be nil and the if statement in the view should resolve then as false. Code snippets for reference are below.

Here's the view:

```
<div id="blog">

<%= render 'blogs/blog_header' %>

<div class="messages">
    <%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @bloggers %>

<% @bloggers.each do |blogger| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2 class="title"><%= blogger.name %></h2>
        <p class="date_and_author" style="display:inline"><%= blogger.email %></p>
        <% if current_blogger.admin = 1 %>
        <p class="date_and_author" style="display:inline">||</p>
        <button class="button" style="display:inline"><%= link_to "delete", blogger, method: :delete,
                                          data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></button>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

The controller:

```
class BloggersController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_blogger, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /bloggers
# GET /bloggers.json
def index
  @bloggers = Blogger.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end

# GET /bloggers/1
# GET /bloggers/1.json
def show
  @blogger = Blogger.find(params[:id])
end

# GET /bloggers/new
def new
  @blogger = Blogger.new
end

# GET /bloggers/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /bloggers
# POST /bloggers.json
def create
  @blogger = Blogger.new(blogger_params)
    if @blogger.save
      blog_sign_in @Blogger
        flash.now[:success] = "New account successfully created."
      redirect_to "/blogs"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /bloggers/1
# PATCH/PUT /bloggers/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @blogger.update(blogger_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @blogger, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @blogger }
    else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @blogger.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /bloggers/1
# DELETE /bloggers/1.json
def destroy
  Blogger.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to bloggers_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

def blogger_params
    params.require(:blogger).permit(:name, :email, :password, :admin, :password_confirmation)
end

# Confirms a signed-in user
def signed_in_blogger
    unless blog_signed_in?
        flash[:error] = "Please sign in."
        redirect_to blog_signin_path
      end
   end
end
```

And the helper:

```
 # Logs in the given blogger
def blog_sign_in(blogger)
    session[:blogger_id] = blogger.id
end

# Returns the current logged-in blogger (if any)
def current_blogger
    @current_blogger ||= Blogger.find_by(id: session[:blogger_id])
end

# Returns true if the blogger is logged in, false otherwise.
def blog_signed_in?
    !current_blogger.nil?
end

def blog_sign_out
    session[:blogger_id] = nil
    @current_blogger = nil
end
```

Could this be somewhat related to a separate error in which when trying to create a new blogger, after hitting create, I get "undefined method id for nil:Class?" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Pasting blogger model per request:

```
class Blogger < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :remember_token
has_secure_password

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true
validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

def Blogger.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def Blogger.digest(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = Blogger.digest(Blogger.new_remember_token)
end
end
```

Comment: First of all your `current_blogger.admin` check is wrong. You are assigning it to the value 1 where if should be a check of value like so `if current_blogger.admin == 1`

Comment: Yup, you're right, shoot. Fixed it, though that didn't fix the issue. Still getting the same error.

Comment: undefined method id?

Comment: No, in the view it's undefined method 'admin'

Comment: could you paste in your blogger model

Comment: Just put it up there. Originally I thought it might be an issue with 'attr_accessible', but that including admin didn't change the problem.

Comment: What is the relationship between an admin and blogger ?

Comment: Admin is a blogger attribute. It's an integer currently as opposed to a boolean. My ultimate goal is to have a greater admin (with int value 1) and some other bloggers who can make posts, but not edit and delete other bloggers in the system (who would have int value 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not signed in and `current_blogger` is `nil` as you say, `admin` won't be an available method.  To avoid this error, change your if statement in the view to something like this.

```
<% if current_blogger && current_blogger.admin == 1 %>
```

You could also use the `try` method, which will also work

```
<% if current_blogger.try(:admin) == 1 %>
```

Comment: Hmm, so it solves the issue of viewing when not signed in, but now doesn't allow the admin to delete users. Tried it using both lines of code.

Comment: No error message, so the code works, just doesn't seem to be recognizing the user as an admin as it did before.

Comment: Is `#admin` really supposed to return `1` when set?  It seems to me that it would be more logical to have it be an explicit boolean.  If you're unsure, try comparing it to `== true`, or post your schema representation for the blogger model.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm just going to redo it as a boolean but have something like admin and superuser or something along those lines.